# PhantomJS has crashed. Very simple code

Tags: phantomjs

**Which version of PhantomJS are you using?**

2.1.1

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

Run that simple code

```
'use strict';

var webpage = require('webpage');

var page = webpage.create();

page.open('https://claimwith.me/', function(status){
    console.log('status: ' + status);
});
```

**Which operating system are you using?**

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

**Did you use binary PhantomJS or did you compile it from source?**

Binary

**Additional information**

1. Run script
2. The page return status=success
3. Wait ~5-10 sec. and phantom crashes

   PhantomJS has crashed.
   Please read the bug reporting guide at http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html and file a bug report.
   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This bug reproduce only on my ubuntu. When run that code on Mac or Window it is OK.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on Arch Linux.

Comment: How do you solved this issue, am also facing the same in Ubuntu